# Pressing a button and assigning its value to jtextfield

Tags: java, button, jtextfield

I am trying to make a sudoku and I want the user to be able to **select a square** from the grid (like on the picture square[0,0] is selected) and then to be able to press one of the **buttons** above from 1 to 9 and **assign the corresponding value** to the selected **textfield**.The textfield is disabled. E.g. now the user presses button with number 3 and the textfield corresponding to [0,0] has value 3. Is there a way to do that? If not I am having trouble restricting the value of the textfield to integers from 1 to 9, I read some posts but I still don't know how to do it with a key handler. I would appreciate help with either one of the approaches. Thanks!

[image]

Here is some of my code:

```
public class Sudoku extends JPanel {

    private static final int CLUSTER = 3;
    private static final int SIZE = 9;
    private static final int BORDER_SIZE = 2;
    private static final Color BG = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
    private SudokuCell[][] cellGrid = new SudokuCell[SIZE][SIZE];

    public Sudoku() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(CLUSTER, CLUSTER));
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(BORDER_SIZE, BORDER_SIZE, BORDER_SIZE, BORDER_SIZE));
        mainPanel.setBackground(BG);
        JPanel[][] panels = new JPanel[CLUSTER][CLUSTER];
        for (int i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < panels[i].length; j++) {
                panels[i][j] = new JPanel(new GridLayout(CLUSTER, CLUSTER));
                panels[i][j].setBackground(BG);
                panels[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(BORDER_SIZE, BORDER_SIZE, BORDER_SIZE, BORDER_SIZE));
                mainPanel.add(panels[i][j]);
            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < cellGrid.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < cellGrid[row].length; col++) {
                cellGrid[row][col] = createCell(row, col);
                int i = row / 3;
                int j = col / 3;
                panels[i][j].add(cellGrid[row][col]);
            }
        }

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private SudokuCell createCell(int row, int col) {
        SudokuCell cell = new SudokuCell(row, col);
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        return cell;
    }
}
```

The **SudokuCell** class extends **JTextField** and has attributes **column** and **row**.

Comment: I see no JButtons in your code.  Have you read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html ?

Comment: Are you facing any specifc problems? The steps you desribe to accomplish your wanted behaviour are probably doable, so 'yes' is the answer to your question. But that probably does not help you or does it?

Comment: yeah, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @VGR this is the code only for the grid. The buttons are just normal JButtons with labels from 1 to 9. I did not know what part of the code would be useful. I thought that maybe some handler must be added to the createCell method. The other parts of the code are just some buttons and menus created with no functionality yet.

Comment: Have you set either an [Action](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) or an ActionListener on each of those buttons?

Comment: No, nothing yet. I did not know how to bind them to the jtextfields. It's just the gui for now, no functionality.